# Validate HTML form entries with Regex Patterns

Tags: javascript, regex, html, forms, validation

I currently use a regex pattern that prevents = being used in form entries. I wish to extend this to only allow form entries in this fields from certain urls? How can I add a wildcard domain regex entry AND maintain using the other = pattern?

```
<input name="url" pattern="[^=]+" type="url" placeholder="Amazon URL" required>
```

VALID ENTRIES

https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01DFKBL68
https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07H3NY1H6/
https://www.amazon.co.uk/b/ref=footer_topup_uk?ie=UTF8&node=13958953031&tag=deals70-21

INVALID ENTRIES

[https://www.amazon.com/Disc-O-Bed-Large-with-Organizers-Black/dp/B01GSA9O3O](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GSA9O3O)
https://www.google.com

Here is what I have so far, which isn't working:

```
pattern="[^=|https://www.amazon.co.uk/*]+"
```

Comment: `pattern="(?!https://www.amazon.co.uk/)[^=]+"`

Comment: Your question is confusing. You are saying = is not allowed in input but then in valid entries you are giving a url having = inside it. That is conflicting. Please be clear. Also the regex you are making is incorrect and seems like you were trying to write it like this pattern="[^=]|(https://www.amazon.co.uk/)*+"

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
pattern="(?!https://www\.amazon\.co\.uk/)[^=]+"
```

The HTML5 pattern regex is automatically put inside `^(?:` and `)$`, so it will look like `^(?:(?!https://www\.amazon\.co\.uk/)[^=]+)$`:

- `^(?:` - start of string and of a non-capturing outer container group
- `(?!https://www\.amazon\.co\.uk/)` - the string cannot start with `https://www.amazon.co.uk/`
- `[^=]+` - one or more chars other than `=`
- `)$` - end of the non-capturing group and the end of the string.